# pyspark hiveContext error while executing spark-submit application to yarn and remote CDH kerberized env

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, cloudera-cdh

error occurs while executing

```
airflow@41166b660d82:~$ spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --keytab keytab_name.keytab --principal --jars keytab_name@REALM --jars /path/to/spark-hive_2.11-2.3.0.jar sranje.py
```

from airflow docker container not in CDH env (not managed by CDH CM). sranje.py is simple select * from hive table.

App is accepted on CDH yarn and executed twice with this error:

```
...
2020-12-31 10:11:43 INFO  StateStoreCoordinatorRef:54 - Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sranje.py", line 21, in <module>
    source_df = hiveContext.table(hive_source).na.fill("")
  File "/dfs/dn4/yarn/nm/usercache/etladmin/appcache/application_1608187067076_0150/container_e29_1608187067076_0150_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 366, in table
  File "/dfs/dn4/yarn/nm/usercache/etladmin/appcache/application_1608187067076_0150/container_e29_1608187067076_0150_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 721, in table
  File "/dfs/dn4/yarn/nm/usercache/etladmin/appcache/application_1608187067076_0150/container_e29_1608187067076_0150_02_000001/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
  File "/dfs/dn4/yarn/nm/usercache/etladmin/appcache/application_1608187067076_0150/container_e29_1608187067076_0150_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 79, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog':"
2020-12-31 10:11:43 ERROR ApplicationMaster:70 - User application exited with status 1
2020-12-31 10:11:43 INFO  ApplicationMaster:54 - Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 1, (reason: User application exited with status 1)
...
```

We assume that "some .jar's and java dependencies" are missing. Any ideas?

**Details**

1. there is a valid krb ticket before executing spark cmd
2. if we ommit `--jars /path/to/spark-hive_2.11-2.3.0.jar`, pyhton error is different

```
...
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':"
...
```

3. versions of spark(2.3.0), hadoop(2.6.0) and java are same as CDH
4. hive-site.xml, yarn-site.xml etc are also provided and valid
5. this same spark-submit app executes OK from node inside of CDH cluster
6. we tried adding additional `--jars spark-hive_2.11-2.3.0.jar,spark-core_2.11-2.3.0.jar,spark-sql_2.11-2.3.0.jar,hive-hcatalog-core-2.3.0.jar,spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.3.0.jar`
7. developers use this code as an example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext, HiveContext, functions as F
from pyspark.sql.utils import AnalysisException
from datetime import datetime

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
hiveContext = HiveContext(sc)

current_date = str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

hive_source = "lnz_ch.lnz_cfg_codebook"
source_df = hiveContext.table(hive_source).na.fill("")

print("Number of records: {}".format(source_df.count()))
print("First 20 rows of the table:")
source_df.show(20)
```

8. different script, same error

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("ZekoTest").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    data = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM lnz_ch.lnz_cfg_codebook")
    data.show(20)
    spark.close()
```

Thank you.

Comment: did you `enableHiveSupport` when creating the spark session?

Comment: i'll paste the code example in question. since i'm not a dev...

Comment: please edit your question to include more details, not putting additional details in the comments. The code is not readable in the comments.

Comment: failed with
`AttributeError: type object 'SparkContext' has no attribute 'enableHiveSupport'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive dependecies are resolved with:

- downloading [hive.tar.gz](https://archive.apache.org/dist/hive/) with exact version of CDH Hive
- created symlinks from hive/ to spark/
  `ln -s apache-hive-1.1.0-bin/lib/*.jar spark-2.3.0-bin-without-hadoop/jars/`
- additional jars downloaded from maven repo to spark/jars/

```
hive-hcatalog-core-2.3.0.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar
spark-hive_2.11-2.3.0.jar
spark-hive-thriftserver_2.11-2.3.0.jar
```

- refresh env var

```
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$(find $HADOOP_HOME -name '*.jar' | xargs echo | tr ' ' ':')
SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath)
```

beeline works, but pyspark throws error

```
2021-01-07 15:02:20 INFO  StateStoreCoordinatorRef:54 - Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sranje.py", line 21, in <module>
    source_df = hiveContext.table(hive_source).na.fill("")
  File "/dfs/dn12/yarn/nm/usercache/etladmin/appcache/application_1608187067076_0207/container_e29_1608187067076_0207_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 366, in table
  File "/dfs/dn12/yarn/nm/usercache/etladmin/appcache/application_1608187067076_0207/container_e29_1608187067076_0207_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 721, in table
  File "/dfs/dn12/yarn/nm/usercache/etladmin/appcache/application_1608187067076_0207/container_e29_1608187067076_0207_01_000001/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
  File "/dfs/dn12/yarn/nm/usercache/etladmin/appcache/application_1608187067076_0207/container_e29_1608187067076_0207_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/dfs/dn12/yarn/nm/usercache/etladmin/appcache/application_1608187067076_0207/container_e29_1608187067076_0207_01_000001/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o31.table.
: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: METASTORE_CLIENT_SOCKET_LIFETIME
```

But, that's another question. Thank you all.